# Python Else won't work with Modules imported?

Tags: python, if-statement, module

I've been testing stuff with modules specifically time module,
and I tried doing "Else", but I just get a syntax error over the "Else", I've looked over the internet a lot, and on here, and I can't find anything, so I decided to ask Myself, I'm probably going to sound like the stupidest person on earth because of this.

Here's my code,

```
import time

input ("Hello, would you like to sleep?")
if input == "Yes":
    time.sleep(0.5)
print("Sleeping.")
print("Sleeping..")
print("Sleeping...")
print("You have awoken!")


else:
print("Alright.")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your program should be like,

```
import time
inputString = input("Hello, would you like to sleep?")
if inputString.lower() == "yes":
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print("Sleeping.")
    print("Sleeping..")
    print("Sleeping...")
    print("You have awoken!")
else:
    print("Alright.")
```

`input` is a keyword in python, you can use that to refer something else, but it is highly discouraged. Also, `input()` returns `string` in python 3.x and `eval(input())` in python 2.x

You know, indentation is very important in Python.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to review your indentation for this. Remember, Python uses whitespace to denote code blocks. It may be that the editor has mangled your code, but it should look like:

```
import time

inputString = input("Hello, would you like to sleep?")
if input == "Yes":
    print("Sleeping.")
    print("Sleeping..")
    print("Sleeping...")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print("You have awoken!")
else:
    print("Alright.")
```

Note that the if and the else are at the same level of indentation, and everything inside of there block is indented one level.